# Number of possible actions the player may take in each ATARI arcade game

Tags: data-request, games

I am looking for a dataset containing:

- the list of [ATARI arcade games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Atari_arcade_games)
- the number of possible actions the player may take in each game (e.g., 4)

Ideally:

- the name of each action (e.g.,  press left)